# Use of moved value when matching on a value that implements Into<String>

Tags: rust, match

I want a function which accepts both `&str` and `String`. The only way I know to do this is by using `Into<String>`.

However, inside the function, I'm trying to match the `Into<String>`. This causes some issues, as the arm is a `&str`.

This is what I have (stripped down):

```
struct Location {
    language: String,
}

fn new<Str>(language: Str) -> Location
where
    Str: Into<String>,
{
    Location {
        language: {
            match &*language.into() {
                "canada" => "ca".to_owned(),
                "uk" => "uk2".to_owned(),
                _ => language.into(),
            }
        },
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

This generates the error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `language`
  --> src/main.rs:14:22
   |
11 |             match &*language.into() {
   |                     -------- value moved here
...
14 |                 _ => language.into(),
   |                      ^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `language` has type `Str`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

My goal is to have allow anything to be passed in, with `canada` and `uk` getting swapped out (everything else being left alone).

Right now, it's converting `language` to a `&str` for the match operator, which works great. The only problem is I still need the reference to `language` for the default arm.

How should I go about approaching this? Is there some trivial way to do this I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust is smart enough to see that your `_ =>` arm of the match statement does not actually borrow the value, so you can do

```
fn new<Str>(language: Str) -> Location
where
    Str: Into<String>,
{
    Location {
        language: {
            let s = language.into();
            match &*s {
                "canada" => "ca".to_owned(),
                "uk" => "uk2".to_owned(),
                _ => s,
            }
        },
    }
}
```

([On the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=188d39301f2e98df3566710669b55899&version=stable))

Comment: Ok, stupid question time. What exactly is the difference (to the compiler) between that and what I had in the post? Certainly there's something, as the compiler no longer complains.

Comment: The `.into()` function's signature is `fn into(self) -> T` so it takes ownership of `language`, which means you cannot use `language` again.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Ownership is still something I'm getting used to. Thanks!

Comment: Besides working, this is more performant; what if `into()` was very expensive?